# Was The Mountain dubbed in season 4 of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, production

Was the actor who played Ser Gregor Clegane dubbed by another actor during his most important dialogue in season 4 of Game of Thrones?

During his most important lines, he seemed almost too good to be true compared to the guy reciting lines in the previous episode - "who am I fighting?". Also there is the fact that the actor who played Ser Gregor is not a professional actor but actually a World's Strongest Man competitor.

Comment: IMDB describes him as an actor... but his only other role listed is as "Big Jon - Icelandic Viking Squad" in some Icelandic zombie movie... http://www.imdb.com/name/nm5491087/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t33

Comment: I don't know but you can find videos of him online where he's speaking English fairly fluently. I'm sure he could handle a line or two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *seems* he was dubbed over by [**Richard Ridings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Ridings), but I haven't been able to pin this down completely.

- In [this forum thread](https://forum.subterraneangames.com/threads/the-mountain-that-talks-possible-game-of-thrones-spoilers.6027/), two people say they **asked Ridings himself in person and he said yes**, he did do a dub-over for Gregor Clegane, at least when Hafthor Bjornsson was playing him and probably for Conan Stevens and Ian Whyte as well.
- Another user on the same discussion thread says this was mentioned on [Ridings's IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0725956/), but it doesn't seem to be there any more.
- A comment on [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQTGKS2T_Eg) (I know, I'm scraping the bottom of the barrel here) says Ridings must have overdubbed Gregor Clegane's voice even though he's not credited for it anywhere.

Finally, in [this article](http://winteriscoming.net/2013/08/30/mountain-recast/) from before Series 4 aired, it is noted that Bjornsson **speaks English with a strong Icelandic accent**, and speculated that his voice may be dubbed over if he gets any dialogue (which he did).

Comment: I came to this exact conclusion myself just forgot to post the answer. If you listen to Ridings other voice work, he sounds very much like Sir Gregor in that scene.